# What's the simplest way to bind a list of checkboxes to a list of checked values

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a list of `AvailableItems` that I want to display as a list of checkboxes, so that users can pick which items to generate, which are then stored in another list called `ItemsToGenerate` (my lists are actually just lists of strings).

Showing all available items with corresponding checkboxes is easy:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
</ItemsControl>
```

But now I need to bind each Checkbox.IsChecked property, to the fact that the item is in the `ItemsToGenerate` list. I thought of making a `ListContainmentToBoolConverter` like this:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=ItemsToGenerate, 
            Converter={StaticResource ListContainmentToBoolConverter}}"
```

But that doesn't work because I'm missing a `ConverterParameter` to pass the value of each item, but I can't do that, because `ConverterParameter` does not support binding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem.

I've changed my `ItemsControl` to a `ListBox`, and added a binding between the SelectedItems with my `ItemsToGenerate` collection using the technique described [here](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html). It basically allows me to synchronize any custom collection to `ListBox.SelectedItems` using a simple attached property.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItems}"
         Behaviors:MultiSelectorBehaviours.SynchronizedSelectedItems=
             "{Binding ItemsToGenerate}"
         SelectionMode="Multiple"
         Background="{x:Null}">  
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />                    
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"
                      Margin="3"
                      IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource=
                           {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                           Path=IsSelected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I'm still able to display this as I initially wanted (a list of checkboxes), by adding a data template to change each `ListBoxItem` to a checkbox and binding each `Checkbox.IsChecked` to `ListBoxItem.IsSelected`.

I had this pattern in so many places in my application that this is the ideal solution for me, because now I just need to specify one attached property, and the rest is all handled by the data bindings, and I don't need any additional code.

Comment: I would like to see the implementation of your attached property. Unfortunately this only works if you reuse the selection from the ListBox but what if your using an ItemsControl with a checkbox within the template?

Comment: I tried this and the end result is a little funky looking (http://i.imgur.com/ZRyrjfe.png). I'm going to stick with a plain ListBox, personally.

Answer (score 11):

I honestly would create a list of objects containing both the string and a boolean indicating if it is checked.

With a little Linq you can generate your list of objects and bind it to itemSource  instead of binding the list of strings.

It will be simpler in the end, especially if you actually need to update something if the user is allowed to check/uncheck the checkboxes.

== update ==

in answer to the comment, my take on this because I'm not sure I understand what the actual problem would be: provided we have the full list (AvailableItems) and the list of selected items (ItemsToGenerate):

```
public class ItemEntry
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected {get; set; }
}
```

...

```
_Items = from item in AvailableItems
            select new ItemEntry() { 
                    Name = item, 
                    IsSelected = ItemsToGenerate.contains(item)
                  }).ToList();
```

You can then bind your list like so, by exposing _Items as a property named Items:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
</ItemsControl>
```

You can at a later time select from _Items where IsSelected is true to get the selected items if you need to.

Also, if ItemsToGenerate can get big, you should create a HashSet of the values and use it in the query, that should make it faster if need be.

Comment: The reason I don't want to do that is because my data is saved to xml and edited by hand sometimes. So if there's 300 items available and they just want to generate 2 items, I want them just to write <ItemsToGenerate><string>Item1</string><string>Item2</string></ItemsToGenerate>.

Comment: I've thought of another way to go about this: using a ListBox where the item template binds the checkbox.IsChecked to the ListItem.IsSelected. Then it would just be a question of binding ItemsSource to the AvailableItems and binding the SelectedItems to ItemsToGenerate.

Comment: Your method using linq however seems it would do what I want, so I'll give it a try. But I'll have to manually update the ItemsToGenerate using Linq if I understand (its not a binding). The reason I'd prefer this to be as simple as possible is that I have a lot of places where I will have this pattern: Choosing which targets to compile, which languages to use, which worlds to generate, which missions to run, etc. I want to minimize the data format, but show all available options in the UI.

Comment: you could possiblyvuse a multibinding with a multivalueconverter if you want to pull off your original idea. It would take no parameter and bind to both the item and the ItemsToGenerate collection.

Comment: I tried making a multivalueconverter, binding the first value to the item, and the second value to the list ItemsToGenerate, and I return true of false correctly if the item is in the list of not. But how can I convert back? The convert back methods just receives a bool. I'm missing the list & item values so I can add/remove the item to the list.

Comment: hmm, yes, I forgot about that part. I guess you're back to one of the other option.

Comment: This worked nearly perfectly.  Instead of a POD object though, I linked to the thing I was actually turning on/off.  Something like:  IFoo{bool Enabled {get;set;}; string Name{get;set;} then ItemEntry has a reference to IFoo and the two properties are linked directly to it like this:              public bool IsSelected
            {
                get => _foo.Enabled;
                set => _foo.Enabled = value;
            }