# Can you use ValidationRules on ListBox.SelectedItems?

Tags: wpf, validation, validationrules

I want to use `ValidationRules` to verify that a few `ListBox` controls have at least one item selected.

I tried doing it this way:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableItems}"
         Behaviors:MultiSelectorBehaviours.SynchronizedSelectedItems="{Binding ChosenItems}"
         x:Name="ListBoxItems">  
    <ListBox.Tag>
        <Binding ElementName="ListBoxItems" Path="SelectedItem">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ValidationRules:NotNullValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </ListBox.Tag>
</ListBox>
```

But my `NotNullValidationRule` never gets called. Note that the `SynchronizedSelectedItems` is a special attached property I use to synchronize the `SelectedItems` to a custom collection ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782980/whats-the-simplest-way-to-bind-a-list-of-checkboxes-to-a-list-of-checked-values/786764#786764)). That's why I do my validation on a 'fake' `Binding` applied to `Tag` instead.

Is there a way to validate `ListBox.SelectedItems`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation is done only in TwoWay and OneWayToSource mode bindings. If you turn the Binding around, binding SelectedItem to tag in either TwoWay or OneWayToSource mode the validation is triggered.

Validation is there to protect the target property. So when you set Tag, validation makes sure the Tag is valid and SelectedItem can be set with a new value. The following code works (SelectedItem binds TwoWay automatically IIRC.)

```
<ListBox x:Name="list">
    <ListBox.SelectedItem>
        <Binding ElementName="list" Path="Tag">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:SelectedValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </ListBox.SelectedItem> 
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works just like I want now.