# Using A checkbox inside a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, itemtemplate

I have this List box:
Here is the Code for my ListBox:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="List" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ShoppingItems}" FontSize="42" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,-15,0,22">
                            <Checkbox x:Name="MyCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Margin="0,-15,0,22" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayingItem}" FontSize="46" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock Text="quantity" FontSize="32" Grid.Row="1" Margin="6,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayingQuantity}" FontSize="32" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="32,0,12,12" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="32" Margin="32,0,12,12" Text="{Binding DisplayingPackaging}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="price" Margin="6,0,0,0" FontSize="32" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="$" FontSize="32" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="32,0,12,12" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" FontSize="32" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="32,0,12,12" Text="{Binding DisplayingPrice}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

it has a checkbox inside, the ListBox is populated by data from a SQLite db. I want when I check the Checkbox to receive a message showing me the name of the SelectedItem of the ListBox.
Here is the Property for my CheckBox

```
private bool isChecked;
    public bool  IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
             if(this.SelectedItem != null)
             {
                 return this.selectedItem.IsChecked;
             }
             return false;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isChecked = value;
        }

    }
```

When I check my Checkbox and Click This Button:

```
private void CheckedItem(object p)
    {

        if (this.IsChecked != false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Checked");
        }
    }
```

Nothing Happens.
I have included my Checkbox in my SelectedItem Like this:

```
private ShowingModel selectedItem;
    public ShowingModel SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if(this.selectedItem != value)
            {
                this.selectedItem = value;
                if (this.selectedItem != null)
                {
                    this.product = selectedItem.DisplayingItem;
                    this.price = selectedItem.DisplayingPrice;
                    this.qty = selectedItem.DisplayingQuantity;
                    this.package = selectedItem.DisplayingPackaging;
                    this.isChecked = selectedItem.IsChecked;
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyPackage");
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyPrice");
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyProduct");
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyQty");
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
    }
```

So Where is the Problem.

Comment: `Help me` - [This Post](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) contains very useful information. Please read it.

Comment: it is dependent to what do u mean by show message(MessageBox?), or you want to fire an event when checking the box?

Comment: I have posted more information.

Comment: pls check the output for any debugging error.

Comment: no Errors the app is running, im I doing anything wrong??

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but too much for a comment
This is just messed up
You need to read up on data binding and start over

The following get and set don't refer to the same value

```
private bool isChecked;
public  bool IsChecked
{
    get
    {
         if(this.SelectedItem != null)
         {
             return this.selectedItem.IsChecked;
         }
         return false;
    }
    set
    {
        this.isChecked = value;
    }
}
```

No indication SelectedItem is bound to anything

On CheckedItem that is not the signature of an event handler

Answer (score 0):

Like @Blam said your immediate problem is resolveable by actually setting an event handler for the CheckBox "MyCheckBox."

```
<CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" 
Checked="MyCheckBox_Checked"/>

private void MyCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Checked");
}
```

2 other things:

- If you keep the property `public ShowingModel SelectedItem`, then I would move the `RaisePropertyChanged` inside of the if statement. Better yet, make each of the variables you're setting their own property like:

  ```
  double MyPrice
  {
      get {return price;}
      set { if(price >= 0.0)/* Don't want a negative price. \m/*/ 
              { price = value; RaisePropertyChanged("MyPrice"); } }
  }
  ```

  If you have it this way for deleting an item, then I would suggest making that clearer for future reference.
- I would highly suggest you take a look at few other resources:

  1. [Databinding a listbox to an ObservableCollection in code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647951/simple-wpf-databinding-of-a-listbox-to-an-observablecollection-of-strings) <-- The question was correct, and has the best way to do this.
  2. [Databinding a listbox to an ObservableCollection in XAML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688193/binding-observable-collection-to-listbox-in-xaml)
  3. [WPF Tutorial | DataTemplates.](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html)
  4. [Making the list item check the checkbox.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782980/whats-the-simplest-way-to-bind-a-list-of-checkboxes-to-a-list-of-checked-values)